# How can I execute an "Explain" statement with a prepared query in PostgrSQL that has bind parameters?

Tags: postgresql

I would like to be able to execute an explain statement on a query that has bind parameters. For example:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM metasyntax WHERE id = $1;
```

When I attempt to execute this, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: bind message supplies 0 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 1
```

I understand it's telling me that it wants me to supply a value for the query. However, I may not necessarily know the answer to that. In other SQL dialects such as Oracle, it will generate an explain plan without needing me to supply a value for the parameter.

Is it possible to get an explain plan without binding to an actual value? Thanks!

Comment: The execution plan could depends on the parameter's value: [example](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=cd52792a97ce9c34bc3e9dfbce041292)

Comment: No. The optimiser is allowed to change the query plan based on the parameter.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming the parameter is an integer:

```
PREPARE x(integer) AS SELECT * FROM metasyntax WHERE id = $1;
```

Then run the following six times, where “42” is a representative value:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) EXECUTE x(42);
```

Normally PostgreSQL will switch to a generic plan for the sixth run, and you will see a plan that contains the placeholder `$1`.

Answer (score 4):

No.

The optimiser is allowed to change the query plan based on the parameter. Imagine if the parameter was `null` - it's obvious that no rows will be returned, so the DB may return an empty rowset instantly.

Just use a representative value.

Comment: Correct. You can, however, `PREPARE` a plan then `EXPLAIN EXECUTE myplan(params)` which can be useful.

Comment: interesting! I always had the understanding that the nature of a prepared statement is to create a query plan in advance to getting passed the actual parameters for execution (to save the effort of recalculating the best query plan every time). however this seemingly contradicts your explanation. can you elaborate where I am wrong?