# How do I get a PostgreSQL execution plan with parameters?

Tags: java, sql, database, postgresql, sql-execution-plan

My application has a myriad of queries and I wanted to get the execution plan of some of them. Most if not
all of the queries have multiple parameters and I can't find how to get the execution plan for any non-trivial query in PostgreSQL.

The real cases are much more involved but here's a simple, representative case of a query (just one parameter for simplicity):

```java
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("...", "...", "...");

PreparedStatement ps1 = conn.prepareStatement(
  "prepare x as select * from documents where content = $1");
ps1.execute();

PreparedStatement ps2 = conn.prepareStatement(
  "explain (format json) execute x (?)");
ps2.setString(1, "Very long content here..."); // Binds the parameter
ResultSet rs = ps2.executeQuery(); // Error here!

while (rs.next()) {
  System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
}
```

When I run this, I get the error:

> ERROR: there is no parameter $1
> Position: 34

If I **hardcode** the parameter (e.g. replacing `$1` with `'a'`) everything works well and I get a plan. However, if I try to use a JDBC parameter it doesn't work. Hardcoding the parameter is not realistic for my use case since it can be a massive parameter or may not be rendered correctly as String (e.g. float value).

I also tried using `null` instead of `?` and it doesn't crash, but
it returns an execution plan that is wrong; it seems it somehow short-circuits the logic and returns something totally off reality.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately that solution is for a different use case. It seems the main answer there is hardcoding the parameter in the second call. That is not realistic for my use case. It can be a massive parameter or may not be rendered correctly as String (e.g. float value).

Comment: I don't use Java, but a little digging found this [Server prepare](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/server-prepare/) *Server Prepared Statements Motivation*. It seems you might need to do: `ps1 = conn.prepareStatement( "select * from documents where content = ?");`

Comment: That's what I'm doing (in the second call). The first one **must use $1** to create a PostgreSQL procedure. I don't understand why the question was closed. The related answer is for a different question.

Comment: 1) I voted to reopen the question as it is different. 2) That is not what you are doing, you are using `prepare` and it's placeholder `$1` in your version of the query. If I understand the docs correctly that taken care of for you by `PreparedStatement`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to replace the `$1` with the *bind variable value*, but you can't apparently use the bind variable in the `explain execute` statement - here it must be stated.

So this sequence works fine (pseudocode)

```
prep = con.prepareStatement("prepare x(integer) as select id, pad from jdbn.document where id = $1")
prep.execute();

stmt = con.prepareStatement("explain execute x (42)")
rs = stmt.executeQuery()
```

As described in the previously marked as duplicated [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44899432/4808122) you get for first few execution a *custom plan* (i.e. you see the variable in the condition, here `id = 42`) and finaly a *generic plan* (i.e. with a predicate `id = $1`)

Your *trick* with `null` fails as PostgreSql knows that  `id = null` returns nothing (I'm using vague formulation to avoid to be neither *true* nor *false*) and makes a *dummy* plan e.g. `One-Time Filter: false`

You may force to produce a *generic plan* with the [`plan_cache_mode`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html) parameter

```
con.createStatement().execute("set plan_cache_mode = force_generic_plan")
```

in which case the the first explained plan is generic. It seem that with this setting the `null` parameter does not lead to a dummy plan (but I'm not sure if there are not other caveats).

So I'd say you should always define the data type of the variable `prepare x(integer) ...`  but I'm not sure and have no experience if you can get a meaningfull execution plan with the combination of `force_generic_plan`  and passing `null` (similar to Oracle functionality) or if you realy must pass representation sample value(s) or the parameter(s).

**Final Note** all the discussion here is focused on *well designed prepared statements*, i.e. any possible value passed will lead to a single same excution plan. For *other* statements it is not meaningfull, as there is *no single execution plan*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I cannot do `explain execute x (42)` since that would require to render the parameter(s) as string(s) (`42` in this case) and concatenate them to the SQL query. In this case some parameters can be massive, or may not be easy to render as strings like floating point numbers. Plus, I don't like to open a window for SQL Injection.

Comment: Sorry to be confusing @JoeDiNottra, I'm not saying you shoud do it this way, I'm only showing how in works in `JDBC`. I also try to point you to the combination of `force_generic_plan` and passing `null` which I'd try to investigate in your situation and check if it provides valuable results.

Comment: When you say "or if you realy must pass representation sample value(s)", that got me thinking. Maybe instead of passing the "very long string", I can just pass a hardcoded "a" value. Maybe that's enough to get a valid plan. If that's the case I just need to make sure I have one hardcoded value for every single PostgreSQL data type, and done!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this line

```
PreparedStatement ps1 = conn.prepareStatement(
  "prepare x as select * from documents where content = '"+ 1 +"'");
ps1.execute();
```

instead of

```
   PreparedStatement ps1 = conn.prepareStatement(
      "prepare x as select * from documents where content = $1");
    ps1.execute();
```